Azure Synapse Pyspark job could see deleted records from CosmosDB
We have Pyspark script that is accessing CosmosDB table (Linked service). We deleted all the records from the CosmosDB table (by decreasing the TTL). But I still see the deleted records from Pyspark job, but I don't see those records from the Azure Portal's Data Explorer.
I am expecting the deleted records to not show when I query from the Pyspark in Azure Synapse workspace..
Spark code reading the CosmosDB:
data = spark.read.format("cosmos.olap")\
.option("spark.synapse.linkedService", "CosmosDBLink")\
.option("spark.cosmos.container", "ContainerName")\
.load()


Please edit to provide more detail. Right now you've only described basic observations, but shared no code/data/errors/etc. Helpful reading: [ask] and writing a [mcve]

@DavidMakogon, Thank you very much for your answer. FYI I have added the spark code for accessing CosmosDB.

This behaviour is entirely expected and is a feature not a bug.
If you wanted the records to be treated as logically deleted from the analytical store you need to actually delete them in the transactional store (not rely on the transactional store ttl).
(Even then they are not truly deleted and can be read with the spark.cosmos.keepAllRecordVersions flag and/or time travel feature but they won't show up in your query results by default)
In order to give the impression of synchronising ttl deletes from the transactional store and the analytical store the ttl and attl would need to be set to the same value (and kept static). Reducing the ttl to delete documents and then putting it back up again subsequently can not be mirrored in the analytical store as the underlying documents are not deleted there and will simply reappear again when the attl is increased.
Now you are in this position it is going to be tricky to resolve however. There is no way to delete the documents from the transactional store and have this propagated to the analytical store as the documents are already gone from the transactional store.
You will likely just need to include a > filter on _ts in your analytical store queries to only include documents from after the point that you want to be treated as the "start again" point.
You would have been better off dropping the collection and recreating it in order to start off again from empty in both the transactional and analytical stores.
